# How to get the data from the Core Data in PickerView? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, uipickerview

There is an application that has a staff list and a list of instructions . And when you create order in a TextField PickerView should appear with a list of employees ( with name ) . I will implement it as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employees"];
        self.empl=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
        UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
        picker.dataSource = self;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
        [self.empTaskField setInputView:picker];
}



 #pragma mark - UIPickerView DataSource Method
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        return self->_empl.count;

    }

    #pragma mark - UIPickerView Delegate Method

    -(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        return [_empl objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

When you click the error appears on the TextField:

> 27/03/2016 23 : 32 : 57.177 Employee Task [ 2730 : 150090 ] -
>   [Employees copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fcf2ac84fd0 2016-03-27 23 : 32 : 57.513 Employee Task [ 2730 :
>   150090 ] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [Employees copyWithZone:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf2ac84fd0'

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your issue is this line: `self.empl=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];` `Employees` doesn't implement `NSCopying` protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `mutableCopy` . NSManagedObject doesn't comform to NSCopying protocol. So your fetch code should be

```
self.empl=[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: В настоящее время в списке вместо nameEmployee написано "NUL" in PickerView

Comment: You need to pass an NSString as the title. For eg 
`return [[_empl objectAtIndex:row] valueForkey:@"empName"];`

Answer (score 0):

=> you should to return as string so you should fetch particulate index row of key and return it..like below code

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{ NSArray
    Teacher *teacher = teacherForSubjectArray[row];
    NSString *teacherName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", teacher.firstName, teacher.middleName, teacher.lastName];
    return teacherName;
}
```

Comment: that  you have to pass as your case :
[_empl objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: It is not solve my problem( Now list in PeckerView  is empty